# Deployment Question

Tags: deployment

We have a live sharepoint site and one development and one UAT server. Whenever we want to refresh the live site content to UAT, we are having problems. Most of the web parts are failing and ending up with the error

"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

This is becuase, most of the webparts takes the custom property of the URL of the browsing website. As the web part does not have any URL when they add to the package for firsttime, all the webparts are failing. We are following the procedure.

1. Take the back up of the whole server farm in live website.
2. Restore to the UAT website.
3. Install the new solution package of the whole application.
   Am I missing anything here? or is there any better way of doing this? How do I make my webpart working without changing the solution package?